# Функторы и операторы в C++

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Я не могу до конца понять, как работает operator() внутри класса и, в принципе, в чем его отличие от методов.

То есть в чем разница между

```
class ManOlderThan
{
    int m_age;
public:
    ManOlderThan( int age )
    {
        m_age = age;
    };
    bool operator()( Man &man )
    {
        if( man.GetAge() > m_age ) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
};

class ManOlderThan
{
    int m_age;
public:
    ManOlderThan( int age )
    {
        m_age = age;
    };
    bool compare( Man &man )
    {
        if( man.GetAge() > m_age ) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
};
```

В том, как потом это вызывать? Или оператор нужен, когда метод только один? Или это вообще разные вещи?

Вообще в данном случае оператор рассматривается в контексте векторов и for_each и find_if

Comment: Что именно непонятно?

Comment: Зачем нужен оператор вместо метода? В чем его преимущество?

Comment: Что значит "отличие от методов"? `operator ()` - это тоже *метод*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Многие алгоритмы используют функциональные объекты для обработки элементов последовательности. В качестве этих функциональных объектов могут выступать функции или классы, имеющие оператор-функцию. Синтаксис вызова для функций и классов - функциональных объектов выглядит идентично. Это позволяет писать обобщенный код. Преимущество классов - функциональных объектов состоит в том. что они позволяют хранить состояние, а также использовать дополнительные поля данных помимо аргументов вызова.

Посмотрите ниже демонстрационную программу, которая находит человека с возрастом больше заданного. Как видно из примера, использование функционального оператора-функции вместо вызова функции-члена класса значительно проще, а также функциональный объект может хранить дополнительную информацию - в данном случае значение 35.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class ManOlderThan
{
    int m_age;
public:
    ManOlderThan( int age ) : m_age( age )
    {
    }

    int GetAge() const 
    {
        return m_age;
    }

    bool operator ()( const ManOlderThan &man ) const
    {
        return m_age < man.GetAge();
    }

    bool compare( const ManOlderThan &man ) const
    {
        return m_age < man.GetAge();
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<ManOlderThan> v = { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 };

    auto man = std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), ManOlderThan( 35 ) );

    std::cout << man->GetAge() << std::endl;

    man = std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), 
                        []( const ManOlderThan &man  )
                        {
                            return ManOlderThan( 35 ).compare( man );
                        } );

    std::cout << man->GetAge() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
40
40
```

То есть программа ищет первого человека в списке людей, заданного вектором, который старше 35 лет.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь стало понятнее. И еще один вопрос: получается, оператор в классе может быть только один (не считая перегрузок), ведь в вызове не указывается никаких идентификаторов, кроме названия класса, правильно?

Comment: @Matty Оператор-функция может быть перегружен как и любая функция по числу и типам параметров, а также по неявному параметру - указателю на объект класса.

Comment: да-да, это понятно, что есть перегрузки. Я про то, что внутри одного класса не может быть несколько разных операторов-функций. Или может?

Comment: @Matty Как раз перегрузка позволяет определять один и тот же оператор-функцию с различными параметрами в одном классе.  Почитайте последнее сообщение о перегрузке функций в указанной теме на моем форуме http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000047-000-40-0

Comment: А, ну конечно. Я сама себя уже запутала. Всё, вопросов больше нет. Спасибо

Comment: а в примере с методом нельзя заменить лямбду на просто передачу метода. как-то так: `std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), ManOlderThan( 35 ).compare)`?

Comment: @Grundy Нужен также объект для этого метода, так как метод не статический. Поэтому код усложняется.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, мы ж его вот создали `ManOlderThan( 35 )` и взяли у него метод `ManOlderThan( 35 ).compare`? или это так не работает?

Comment: @Grundy, достаточно сделать так: `std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), ManOlderThan(35))`. Это, кстати, есть в ответе.

Comment: @ixSci, не, это как раз вариант с операторм `()`, а я говорю про вариант, когда его нет, а есть просто функция сравнения `compare`

Comment: @Grundy, тогда она должна быть либо статической, либо вне класса вообще. Аналога `delegate`, который непрозрачно сохраняет объект в своих недрах в C++ нет — всё нужно делать явно, либо через лямбду, либо через `std::bind`

Comment: @ixSci, ага, теперь понятно